# Jhipster social login with ionic 2

Tags: spring, facebook, cordova, ionic2, jhipster

Use case:

Ionic 2 app using jhispter as a backend.

JWT Auth working fine.

Overview of the issue

I added social auth to jhipster back-end, but i can't figure out a way to communicate the ionic 2 app with the jhipster social login, i was thinking of using cordova inappbrowser to do this but can't figure out how.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: As i said the social login is already implemented in the backend by jhipster  . So i'm open for suggestion on how to do it with Ionic 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me that is not possible to do this with jhipster and ionic directly, perhaps using Auth0 may be a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

[Ignite JHipster](https://github.com/ruddell/ignite-jhipster/) has social login but without ionic